# Executing a stored procedure that is configured in a dataset's .xsd

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, tableadapter

I am having difficulty returning data from a stored procedure I set up in my dataset. So essentially in my xsd I added the table adapter and selected my existing stored procedure [use existing procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D81Na.png) which as you can see returns the columns listed here [returned columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepgU.png).

This is the stored procedure here [stored procedure I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPkY1.png). I've made sure to add the binding source to the textbox as seen here [Databindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7XpL.png). This is the binding source I am using [Binding Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyQWM.png). Here is the method I am using to get pass a guid to the form [Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8yyZ.png).

I can return data when I choose the default use SQL statements option seen in the first picture and simply write my code as follows.

```
SELECT 
    CustomersID,
    ShopID,
    CompanyID,
    CustomerNumber,
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    Address AS [Address],
    State AS [State],
    City AS City,
    Zip AS Zip,
    HomePhone AS HomePhone,
    HomePhoneExt AS HomePhoneExt,
    WorkPhone AS WorkPhone,
    WorkPhoneExt AS WorkPhoneExt,
    CellPhone AS CellPhone,
    CellPhoneExt AS CellPhoneExt,
    Email AS Email,
    CustomerNotes AS CustomerNotes
FROM
    dbo.tbl_Customers c WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    c.CustomersID = @ID
```

How do I integrate my existing stored procedure using this method to produce the same results so that I can make refactoring stored procedures more efficient and not have to throw out a new build for a simple SQL fix? I'd like to avoid using the `SqlCommand` by `SqlConnection` method if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the stored procedure ... first line is RETURN ... so procedure is returning before doing anything ... RETURN should be at the end.

Try to get the procedure running in SSMS first ... then bring it into the xsd.

[The other hint that something's not right is that in the link for 'returned columns' ... check the heading over the columns ... it thinks they're parameters.]

Comment: Aaaand i feel like a dunce. Thank you!